# Creating a dataframe from an unknown row

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe, row

Say if I have a .csv file that looks like this:

```
0,0
1,1
2,2
3,3
4,4
5,5,5,5
6,6,6,6
7,7,7,7
```

How could I create a dataframe from row 5, without it depending on the row number? Obviously I know you can make the `header=5` but I would like it to do something more like `header=#when it reaches 4 columns#`, whatever that row may be.

I realise that this question was not quite as specific as I needed so I have reiterated it here: [Creating a dataframe from different rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49698531/creating-a-dataframe-from-different-rows)

Answer (score 1):

You could use `str.count` in a comprehension.  Then wrap that in a data frame constructor.

```
from pandas.io.common import StringIO as sio
pd.read_csv(sio(
    ''.join(l for l in open('test.csv') if l.count(',') > 2)
), header=None)

   0  1  2  3
0  5  5  5  5
1  6  6  6  6
2  7  7  7  7
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution would be to first read the csv in as a normal file, filter that file line by line and then use io.StringIO to read the "edited csv" in as dataframe. Caution: this will not be suitable for big files.

For example:

```
import io
import pandas as pd

new_csv = []
with open('csv.csv') as f:
    for line in f:
        if len(line.split(',')) >= 4:
            new_csv.append(line)
file_io = io.StringIO('\n'.join(new_csv))
df = pd.read_csv(file_io)
```